# Why does double tap gesture only work once on UITextView?

Tags: swift, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a textview that I want to allow the user to edit when they double tap. The double tap works fine when the viewcontroller first loads. After I edit the textview and close the textview then reopens for editing with just a single tap. My code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
 let myTaps = UITapGestureRecognizer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   textView.gestureRecognizers = nil
    myTaps.addTarget(self, action: "handleTaps:")
    myTaps.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    myTaps.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

    textView.addGestureRecognizer(myTaps)


}

func handleTaps(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("Taps")
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches as Set<UITouch>, withEvent: event)
}

func textViewShouldEndEditing(textView: UITextView) -> Bool {

    textView.endEditing(true)

    return true
   }




}
```